# Best way to check and assign to object from response?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

With my angular2 application, i am getting the response and assigning to object as follows,

```
 seatingConcession: {
                        parking: data.concession.extras.parking ? data.concession.extras.parking : null,
                        restrictedview: data.concession.extras.restrictedview ? data.concession.extras.restrictedview : null,
                        wheelchair: data.concession.extras.wheelchair ? data.concession.extras.wheelchair : null
                    }
```

sometimes extras does not have value. sometimes restrictedview inside extras does not have value. what is the best way to check and assign the default value .
Whole code:

```
 this.eventService.getListingsByEventId(this.eventId).subscribe(listresults => {
            this.bindListing(listresults);
        }, error => this.errorMessage = error);
    }
    bindListing(listres: any[]) {
        let price_table = {};
        let section_table = {};
        listres.forEach((data) => {
            data.ticket.seating.forEach((seat: any) => {
                // tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
                this.listings.push({
                    section: seat.section, selling: data.price.selling, amount: data.ticket.amount, type: data.ticket.type, row: seat.row, category: seat.category,
                    seatingConcession: {
                        parking: data.concession.extras ? (data.concession.extras.restrictedview || null) : null,
                        restrictedview: data.concession.extras.restrictedview || null,
                        wheelchair: data.concession.extras.wheelchair  || null
                    },
                    deliveryconcession: {
                        instantdownload: data.delivery.instantdownload || null,
                        readytoship: data.delivery.readytoship  || null,
                        unespecifiedshipment: data.delivery.unspecifiedshipment  || null
                    }
                });
                // this.listings.push({ section: seat.section, selling: data.price.selling, amount: data.ticket.amount, type: data.ticket.type, row: seat.row, category: seat.category});
                // tslint:disable-next-line:curly
                if (!price_table.hasOwnProperty(data.price.selling))
                    price_table[data.price.selling] = [];
                price_table[data.price.selling].push(data);
                // tslint:disable-next-line:curly
                if (!section_table.hasOwnProperty(seat.section))
                    section_table[seat.section] = [];
                section_table[seat.section].push(data);
            });
        });
```

Service js:

```
 getListingsByEventId(EventID: string): Observable<ListingSeller[]> {
        let apiurl = this.appConfig.getAPIUrl() + '/getListingsByEventId';

        return this.http
            .get(apiurl + queryString)
            .map(this.extractData)
            .catch(this.handleErrors);
    }
```

Comment: If data.concession.extras.parking is null, there's no need to do that, is there?

Comment: try this, which will satisfy both conditions `data.concession.extras ? (data.concession.extras.restrictedview || null) : null`

Comment: @Satpal same issue

Comment: @Sravan i am getting restrictedview as null

Comment: @user2280016 you may not have the value in `restrictedview`

Comment: @Sravan yes thats my question , how to handle those?

Comment: Please, post the whole code. It may be appropriate to do this inside observable.

Comment: @estus updated the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following function to achieve what you want.

```
function getSafe(fn) {
    try {
        return fn();
    } catch (e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then use it like this

```
seatingConcession: {
    parking: getSafe(() => data.concession.extras.parking),
    restrictedview: getSafe(() => data.concession.extras.restrictedview),
    wheelchair: getSafe(() => data.concession.extras.wheelchair),
}
```

See [details](https://silvantroxler.ch/2017/avoid-cannot-read-property-of-undefined/).

Another approach would be to execute `data.concession.extras = data.concession.extras || {}` before actually creating your object.

Comment: is this applicable in typescript?

Comment: @user2280016 Yes it is.

Comment: cannot find name getSafe

Comment: @user2280016 Did you actually define the function `getSafe`?

Comment: Usually I don't downvote the sibling answers. But the problem with this approach is that it definitely isn't the 'best way'. It is SLOW. Mindless use of a bunch of try...catch in data processing that could be easily done in another way is just wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned,

"*sometimes extras does not have value. sometimes restrictedview inside extras does not have value*"

so, this condition will help you.

**`data.concession.extras ? (data.concession.extras.restrictedview || data.concession.extras ) : null`**

Here is an example:

**The first example has `restrictedview` and the second example doesn't.**

```js
data = {}
data.concession = { 'extras' :  {} }
data.concession.extras = { 'restrictedview' : 'restrictedview value'}

data2 = {}
data2.concession = { 'extras' : 'extras value' }


var output =  data.concession.extras ? (data.concession.extras.restrictedview || data.concession.extras ) : null

var output2 =  data2.concession.extras ? (data2.concession.extras.restrictedview || data2.concession.extras ) : null


console.log(output)
console.log(output2)
```

**PLEASE RUN THE ABOVE SNIPPET**

Answer (score 0):

Observables do `try...catch`, so for data structures it is possible to follow the pattern:

```
data$
.map(data => data.complex.path || null)
.catch(() => Observable.of(null))
```

But for nested structures this will result in complex observable hierarchy which is hard to comprehend.

So basically it is possible to treat complex paths to values with this recipe:

```
parking: ((data.concession || {}).extras || {}).parking  || null
```

This case is conveniently treated by [Lodash/Underscore `get`](https://lodash.com/docs#get) or a similar helper function:

```
parking: _.get(data, 'concession.extras.parking', null)
```